# Php always returns the same image in JSON

Tags: php, json

[json return this, images are equals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDs1g.png)
How to return image data from MySQL? This code returns always first image.When I fetching only one value, everything is ok.
Please help.

```
 require_once 'connection.php';
        mysqli_query ($conn,"SET NAMES UTF8");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE authorId = '$id' GROUP BY date DESC ";

        $response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $result['posts'] = array();

        if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) > 0 ) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
                    $index['id'] = $row['id'];
                    $index['authorId'] = $row['authorId'];
                    $index['date'] = $row['date'];
                    $index['time'] = $row['time'];
                    $index['description'] = strval($row['description']);
                    $index['picture'] = base64_encode($row['picture']);
                    #echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['picture'] ).'"/>';


                array_push($result['posts'], $index);
                $index['picture'] = null;
                }
                $result['success'] = "1";
                $result['message'] = "success";
                echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

                mysqli_close($conn);

            } else {

                $result['success'] = "0";
                $result['message'] = "error";
                echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

                mysqli_close($conn);

            }
```

Comment: If you **print_r** the **$row** inside the while loop does it return each unique picture in the array?

Comment: It prints everything normal, only the picture is always the same.

Comment: I dont know why you think the two picture base64s are 'the same' ... in your screenshot, they are clearly different base64s. Tip: Dont look at the front, look at the whole.

Answer (score 1):

Set **$index** to an empty array at the start of the while loop, this should clear any existing values from the previous iteration

Comment: The problem still exists :(

Comment: Did you test printing each result individually with print_r as in the above comment? i.e. **print_r($row)** at the top of the while loop

Comment: You can see output on image at the top

Answer (score 0):

you are not resetting $index variable on each row.
just add $index=array(); as below.

```
if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) > 0 ) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
  $index = array(); // this one.

 }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help :(